# Autocorrelation vs correlation calculation

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation

I have set $x = {1,2,3,4,5}$ and set $y = {2,3,4,5,6}$. Lets say the correlation of $x$ and $y$ is $0.7$. If I then have set $z = {1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6}$, and I do autocorrelation using lag $=$ $5$, should I not get the same $0.7$? I have been doing this but I keep getting different results. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or maybe it is that they should have different results.

Comment: The first question is probably answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10947 .

Comment: Please don't ask two separate questions in one. @zbicyclist Please use answers for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

denominators are different in the correlation formula and the autocorrelation formula. (moved to answer at moderator's request)

Comment: The explanation for the difference is provided at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10947/formula-for-autocorrelation-in-r-vs-excel/10950#10950