# Covariance of timeseries

Tags: covariance, excel

If I have data on a time series with the following structure

```
 Day   Value, p
  1     1.2
  2     2.1 
  3     4.0
  4     3.2
```

How do I calculate the first order serial covariance of the value $p$ on day $t$ with the value from the previous day, i.e.  $\text{Cov}(p_t,p_{t-1})$? (I am using Excel)

Comment: Closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10947/formula-for-autocorrelation-in-r-vs-excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Excel has some little-known but powerful functions for operating on arrays.**  Although they are clunky, they work; and knowing how to use them reduces the chance of making errors (and likely improves computational efficiency).  In particular, using these functions helps one to *avoid copying data.*  (Having copies of data in various places creates opportunities for corruption and inconsistency, as well as resulting in a confusing document that is more difficult to check.)

A lagged covariance requires functions to shift (that is, "lag") a vector and to compute covariances.  The shift function is called `OFFSET` and the covariance function is `COVAR`.

I recommend naming arrays rather than using direct references to them.  In this example, let's suppose the range of four cells in which the "Value" data are contained has been named `Values`.  Then an expression to lag this (vertical) array by a number of rows $j$ is

```
OFFSET(Values,j,0,4-j,1)
```

The first occurrence of $j$ shifts `Values` down by $j$ rows.  The second occurrence, in the form $4-j$, cuts off the shifted array at the end so it can match the first $4-j$ entries in `Values`.  Those, too, should be cut using `OFFSET`.  Thence the full formula is

```
=COVAR(OFFSET(Values,0,0,4-j,1), OFFSET(Values,j,0,4-j,1))
```

For the lag-one covariance, just replace "$j$" by "$1$" all three places it occurs.

---

An easy flexible way to study the serial covariances more generally is to create a column of values of $j$, to which this formula may refer.  Type it in once and copy it down its column.  That leads to the following solution in which values $j=0,1,2,3$ (the maximum possible lag is one less than the length of the array) are placed into column `D` and the corresponding lagged covariances are computed with this formula in neighboring column `E`:

[image: Results]

The lag-1 covariance is $0.363,$ shown in cell `E3`.  Here is the full spreadsheet:

[image: Formulas]

---

Please note that in time series analysis one usually computes an *autocorrelation function* (ACF) using a slightly different formula: refer to [Understanding this acf output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81754/understanding-this-acf-output) for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
Day(t)  p(t)  p(t-1)
2       2.1   1.2
3       4     2.1
4       3.2   4
```

$$\text{Cov}(p_t,p_{t-1}) = \text{E}[(p_t - \text{E}[p_t]) \times (p_{t-1} - \text{E}[p_{t-1}])]$$

Go to: Data ---> Data Analysis ---> Covariance

[image]

$\text{Cov}(p_t,p_{t-1}) = 0.3633$

Answer (score 0):

for lag of 1 in col D: Covariance.s($b$2:$b$4,c3:c4) (B's are absolute - not displaying correctly here. Drag down for different lags
Autocovariance both refs in col B