# Correlation dimension vs lag time

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, terminology

I've been looking for fortran code for computing the autocorrelation function like R's `acf` function. The code I have found so far uses some parameter called the **dimension** of correlation. I am used to seeing autocorrelation in terms of **lag**. What is the relationship between the dimension and the lag? Or am I mixing up two different types/concepts of autocorrelation?

**UPDATE** So it does just look like an issue of semantics---at least, for [this implementation](https://math4u.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/autocorrelation-in-fortran/). I got thrown off by [this implementation](https://corcellicodelibrary.wikispaces.com/file/detail/autocorrelation.f90.txt), which seems to be doing something entirely different.

Comment: Programmers can call their variables anything they like, subject to the lexical requirements of the language.

Comment: Thanks @whuber---so you suspect it's just semantics? Have you seen the term "dimension" used to refer to lag?

Comment: Experience has taught me to infer little from the names programmers give to their variables.  Sometimes they can be misleading.  Using "dimension" for lag would be strange--and it would be awful in a Fortran program, too, because of the special role of that word in the language.  Fortunately, I don't see *anything* in either of your links that calls any variable "dimension".  I really can't tell what you might be referring to by this word.

Comment: @whuber, in the first link the author describes the variable `M` as the "dimension" in the post text. In the second link, my exploration of the context for the variable `nmolecules` (which I assumed was a shortcut to allow autocorrelation for multiple variables, rather than having to call the function multiple times) which led me to discussions of autocorrelation between molecular spins and the term [correlation dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_dimension) was used. I still don't understand what the code in the second link is doing, but the first link matches results in R.

Comment: The second link appears to compute the [autocorrelation function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81754), or "acf."