# "Manual" calculation of ACF of a time series in R - close but not quite

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

I'm trying to understand the "mechanism" behind the calculation of ACF values in a time series. As a ["prove-it-to-myself exercise"](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/acf_pacf.html) [NOTE: I updated the code in this link to reflect the information in the accepted answer], I am not focusing on the elegance of the code, and I use loops on purpose. The problem is that, although the values I get are close to those generated by `acf()`, they are not equal, and at some points, not all that close. Is there any conceptual misunderstanding?

As credited on the online notes linked above, the data was generated following [this online example](http://www.christoph-scherber.de/content/Statistics%20Course%20files/A%20short%20introduction%20to%20time%20series%20analysis%20in%20R.pdf).

```
set.seed(0)                          # To reproduce results
x = seq(pi, 10 * pi, 0.1)            # Creating time-series as sin function.
y = 0.1 * x + sin(x) + rnorm(x)      # Time-series sinusoidal points with noise.
y = ts(y, start = 1800)              # Labeling time axis.
model = lm(y ~ I(1801:2083))         # Detrending (0.1 * x)
st.y = y - predict(model)            # Final de-trended ts (st.y)
ACF = 0                              # Empty vector to capture the auto-correlations.
ACF[1] = cor(st.y, st.y)             # The first entry in the ACF is the cor with itself.
for(i in 1:24){                      # Took 24 points to parallel the output of `acf()`
  lag = st.y[-c(1:i)]                # Introducing lags in the stationary ts.
  clipped.y = st.y[1:length(lag)]    # Compensating by reducing length of ts.
  ACF[i + 1] = cor(clipped.y, lag)   # Storing each correlation.
}
w = acf(st.y)                        # Extracting values of acf without plotting.
all.equal(ACF, as.vector(w$acf))     # Checking for equality in values.
# Pretty close to manual calc: Mean relative difference: 0.03611463"
```

To get a tangible sense of the relative outputs, this is what the autocorrelations look like calculated manually:

```
1.0000000 0.3195564 0.3345448 0.2877745 0.2783382 0.2949996 ... 
... -0.1262182 -0.1795683 -0.1941921 -0.1352814 -0.2153883 -0.3423663
```

as opposed to the R `acf()` function:

```
1.0000000 0.3187104 0.3329545 0.2857004 0.2745302 0.2907426 ...
... -0.1144625 -0.1621018 -0.1737770 -0.1203673 -0.1924761 -0.3069342
```

As suggested, this is likely explained comparing to the code in the call within `acf()` in the line:

`acf <- .Call(C_acf, x, lag.max, type == "correlation")`

How can this `C_acf` function be accessed?

---

I am having similar issues with the PACF, which I presume are related. The code for the PACF values is [here](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/acf_pacf.html). [NOTE: In this case I suspect it is actually a rounding difference].

Comment: Have you taken a look at the C code that R uses to compute the ACF?

Comment: @Jon I looked at the R function, and saw that ultimately it refers the data to the `C_acf` procedure (?), and looked it up online without success. I am completely unfamiliar with C.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/q/14035506/1864816

Comment: I downloaded the most recent R source code tarball (R-3.3.2.tar.gz) and searched for "C_acf" but found nothing. I found the acf.R file, which uses C_acf, but not the actual C file. I did however find the pacf C file. This is quite strange.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for looking into it. It seems as though someone has to know the answer; it never helps when a question entails sifting through a chunk of code, like in my OP. It's possible that a more straight to the point question, possibly in SO, could do the trick.

Comment: The problem at this stage is finding the C file. Your question involves understanding how R's algorithm works as your calculations vary significantly. I don't see how posting this question on SO would help.

Comment: @Jon Yes, asked as a software-specific question, such as, "how to find the C file routine", it would arguably be off-topic in CV. But it's a moot point.

Comment: Antoni, have you seen http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81754?

Comment: @whuber +1 and thank you. No, I hadn't. I look forward to reading carefully your post for a deeper understanding of autocorrelation across time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently `cor` and `acf` are not using the same divisor. `acf` uses as divisor the number of observations and can be reproduced as shown below. For details, you can locate the code of `C_acf` in the file `R-3.3.2/src/library/stats/src/filter.c` (procedures `acf` and `acf0`):

```
set.seed(0)                          # To reproduce results
x = seq(pi, 10 * pi, 0.1)            # Creating time-series as sin function.
y = 0.1 * x + sin(x) + rnorm(x)      # Time-series sinusoidal points with noise.
y = ts(y, start = 1800)              # Labeling time axis.
model = lm(y ~ I(1801:2083))         # Detrending (0.1 * x)
st.y = y - predict(model)  
lag.max <- 24
ydm <- st.y - mean(st.y)
n <- length(ydm)
ACF <- rep(NA, lag.max+1)
for (tau in seq(0, lag.max))
  ACF[tau+1] <- sum(ydm * lag(ydm, -tau)) / n
ACF <- ACF/ACF[1]
names(ACF) <- paste0("lag", seq.int(0, lag.max))
ACF
head(ACF)
# lag0      lag1      lag2      lag3      lag4      lag5 
# 1.0000000 0.3187104 0.3329545 0.2857004 0.2745302 0.2907426 
tail(ACF)
# lag19      lag20      lag21      lag22      lag23      lag24 
# -0.1144625 -0.1621018 -0.1737770 -0.1203673 -0.1924761 -0.3069342 
all.equal(ACF, acf(st.y, lag.max=lag.max, plot=FALSE)$acf[,,1], check.names=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you answer the question, and plan on accepting the answer after going over the code with a debugger. I searched online for the file you post, and found it on a fossies.org page. The code there looks rather different - Did you adapt it to R yourself? Is there any other place I should be searching for it? In general, what is the procedure to find these C or Fortran functions?

Comment: I didn't follow the C source code. I simply tried to do a a concise and illuminating implementation for illustration of the operations involved. In practice, it is better to use `acf`, which will for example deal with missing observations.

Comment: Very nice! Can you please add some context to the file you quote? I'll accept your answer anyway, but it would be nice to have a bit of an explanation as to how to resolve these situations where R points to some function in C or Fortran.

Comment: The C or Fortran code is located in the directory `src` of the source packages. The package a function belongs to can be found in the header of the documentation (left-hand-side in brackets). In order to find the function in the directory `src`, it is helpful to use some searching tool such as [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

Comment: Do you access `src` from within RStudio? I use Windows, and was became acquainted with `grep` yesterday reading about it on SO, but I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: I access `src` from the sources available on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/sources.html), file R-3.3.2.tar.gz. Note that the sources of the base packages are on a directory named `src` as well. For other packages not distributed in the above file you can get the sources from its CRAN page, which has the general form https://cran.r-project.org/package=PKG_NAME.