# How does R calculate the acf() function as quickly as it does?

Tags: time-series, estimation, autocorrelation, covariance, algorithms

I noticed that R computes the `acf(data,n)` in order $O(n)$ time, not $O(n^2)$, so it cannot compute it brute force using double for loops. How does R calculate it this quick? What is the algorithm?

Comment: How do you so confidently state that it's $O(n)$ rather than say $O(n\log n)$?

Comment: Note that an explanation of how to see the code that performs R's `acf` function is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254227/manual-calculation-of-acf-of-a-time-series-in-r-close-but-not-quite). I expected it would use a fast Fourier transform, but (at least judging from a quick glance) the `acf`-related parts of `filter.c` don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: @Glen_b In this question, $n$ is the maximum lag, not the data size.  It is apparent that the algorithm, whatever it might be, will be $O(n)$, since the output contains $n+1$ numbers. However, the implicit constant is $N$ where $N$ is the length of the data--and this will dominate the asymptotics, of course (since $N \ge n$). Thus, **this question is misleading:** the algorithm *must* be at least $O(Nn) \ge O(n^2)$, not $O(n)$ or even $O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: $O(Nn) = O(n)$ by definition for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Marius, your comment makes no sense after what @whuber just explained.

Comment: Marius, your assertion is correct *when $N$ does not depend on $n$*.  However, in your question--as I pointed out--necessarily $N$ is no less than $n$.  Thus $N$ cannot be considered a constant (asymptotically in $n$).  In this case it is no longer true that $O(Nn)=O(n)$: it follows that $O(Nn) \ge O(n^2)$.

Comment: I can change it to whatever you want. What would you like, $O(Nn)$? If you know the answer to the original problem, would you like to answer?