# Why does cross-correlation function ccf in R have nonzero values?

Tags: r, cross-correlation

When I try to compute the cross-correlation function between two vectors c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) and c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) via

```
ccf(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I get the following result:
[image]

Here all values are nonzero, which seems strange for me, because for most lags, when I multiply two vectors (for example for zero lag), I should get zero, because where one vector has nonzero element, another has zero and vice versa. 
Why do I get some nonzero results on the graph where I should get zero?

Comment: Hint: you can find a lag where there is at least one term *without* any zeros in its factors.  Don't forget that correlation concerns the *residuals* after means are subtracted.  There's probably also a technical issue similar to that discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81754; namely, there are several slightly different formulas for the ccf in use.

Comment: Yes, I had a lack of understanding how cross-correlation is computed, I didn't know that it is computed for mean-substracted values. When I computed ccf with vectors c(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) and c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1) (which have zero means), I got nonzero elements at lags 1, 2, 3 and everywhere else it is zero, how should be.

Comment: Some people (typically in engineering fields) do not subtract the means in their definition, often because they assume a zero-mean process anyway.  That difference has little impact with the typical long time series ("signals") they work with, but it can have a huge difference with tiny example data like these.