# Example of random process with negative variation

Tags: time-series, covariance, stationarity, example

I study about random processes. 
Let us have $\{X_1, X_2, \dots X_n\}$ observations. I learned, that in stationary time series the sample autocovariance function is defined as

$$
\widehat{γ}(h)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^{n−|h|} (X_{t+|h|} - \overline{X})(X_{t} - \overline{X})$$ 
for $h \in\{{−(n−1),…,(n−1)\}}$ and $\overline{X} = \hat{μ} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is the sample mean.

I wonder, why we devide the sum by $n$. I have read, that if we compute sample autocovariance function like this:

$$
\hat{γ_1}(h)= \frac{1}{n-h} \sum_{t=1}^{n−|h|} (X_{t+|h|} - \overline{X})(X_{t} - \overline{X})
$$

the estimation of variance a linear combination of observations (for example: $X_1 + X_2$)  can possibly be negative
$\widehat {Var}(X_1 + X_2) < 0$.

Could you help me find a concrete example of this? I want to find a concrete realisation of a random proces and a linear combination, that when I count for example:
$$
\widehat {Var}(X_1 + X_2) = \hat{γ_1}(0) + \hat{γ_1}(0) + 2\hat{γ_1}(1) 
$$ 
the variance is negative.

Comment: I believe the discussion at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81754/understanding-this-acf-output/81764#81764 may shed some light on this issue and perhaps even suggest the example you are seeking.

Comment: I add my attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observations $\{3,2,1,0\}, n=4$

I count $ \overline{X}= \frac{3}{2} \hat{γ_1}(0)=\frac{5}{4}, \hat{γ_1}(3)=-\frac{9}{4}$

then

$ \widehat {Var}(X_1 + X_4)=\widehat {Var}(X_1)+\widehat {Var}(X_4)+2\widehat {Cov}(X_1, X_4)= 2\hat{γ_1}(0)+2\hat{γ_1}(3)= \frac{5}{2} - \frac{9}{2} = -2<0$