# Why doesn't max cross-correlation equal exactly 1 between two identical vectors with a designed-in lag? (R, ccf)

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I have two vectors, `a1` and `a2`. They're identical except for a certain lag:

[image]

I expected their cross-correlation to have a maximum of 1 at their lag. However that's not the case: their max cross-correlation is close to 1, but not quite (0.9998). (If I just remove the lag manually and correlate, I of course get a correlation of exactly 1.)

My intuitive understanding was that cross-correlation took two vectors, "slide one over" by a certain amount, and calculated a correlation. Clearly that's not the case, because I don't get a value of exactly 1. **Why isn't the peak 1?**

(This question is followup to [another question I asked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/456142/what-makes-cross-correlation-r-ccf-different-from-sliding-one-of-the-curves), where the discrepancy is much bigger, so **I take this is a general feature of `ccf`**.)

Code

```
# make vectors
a0 = runif(25)
a1 = c(rep(0.5, 2), a0)
a2 = c(a0, rep(0.5, 2))

# plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=1:27, y=a1), color="red") + geom_line(aes(x=1:27, y=a2), color="blue")

# cross-correlate
tmp = ccf(a1, a2, type="correlation", plot=F)
print(paste("maximum correlation is", max(tmp$acf)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. The first question asked why the location of the peak was different between ccf and my intuition. This question is specifically asking why the peak of ccf isn't 1. I edited this question to be more focused ("why isn't the peak 1?").