# I have a graph which appears to be random but there seems to be a pattern hidden in it. How do I analyze it?

Tags: data-visualization, inference

The below graph seems to be random but I think the peaks seem to repeat after a certain period. Are there any statistical tools I can use to analyze this?

[image: The graph I want to analyze]

Edit:
I am adding the plot of its autocorrelation:
[image]

Comment: Yes, an autocorrelation plot.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? I can plot the autocorrelation using some inbuilt function in Matlab but what can I learn from it? Edit: I got a plot that looks like a symmetriacal triangle with double the size of initial array

Comment: Can you post the plot into your question?

Comment: I just did. The original array is 789 while the autocorrelation is its double.

Comment: That's... not possible, autocorrelation is between 0 and 1, your plot goes  to 150...

Comment: Please explain how you made that new plot, it is not an autocorrelation plot.  Please also give (a link to( your data, so we can have a look

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81754 for an explanation of some of the subtleties of autocorrelation coefficient calculations.

Comment: I have used MATLAB's xcorr function. From the website: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html r = xcorr(x) returns the autocorrelation sequence of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot that you made looks like using the function [`xcorr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html) which computes an autocorrelation function without normalization.

$$R(l) = \sum_{\forall k:0\leq k \leq 800 \text{ and } 0\leq k+l \leq 800} R(k)\cdot R(k+l)$$

This is why you get this piramid shape. The number of terms in the sum changes/decline when the lag $l$ gets larger. This makes the sum become less.

---

If you normalize the function then you should get something like

[image: acf]

This function can tell you whether there is a periodic behaviour. For instance there might be peaks repeating every 4 or 8/9 time points.

In my plot you see that the correlation is not very significant (the blue dotted lines point the boundary above/below which the correlations are significant). But, I sampled data from your image. If instead you do this with your raw data then the correlation might be stronger and the pattern could be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect that there are periodic signals in your data, you can analyse it in the [frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain).  I would recommend you start by plotting the signal intensity using the [`intensity`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ts.extend/versions/0.1.1/topics/intensity) function in the `ts.extend` package in `R`.  Intensity spikes in the frequency domain indicate periodic signals in the data, and harmonics of these spikes occur when those periodic signals have a shape that is not perfectly sinusoidal.